# Javascript ou Jquery - como fazer um inventário de classes de divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma div de id=cores e dentro dela tenho outras divs com várias classes

```
<div id="cores">
    <div class="azul">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>       
</div>
```

Gostaria de montar uma função que apurasse quantas divs que com class definida e quantas classes existem de cada elemento.

Não sei se me fiz claro.

Solução da parte um (Fazer uma array só com os nomes das classes).
Achei uma solução com o find:

```
    var array_cores = [];

    $("#cores").find('div').each(function(){
        var classe = $(this).attr("class");
        arrayObjetos.push({classe});
    });

    console.log(array_cores);
```

Gera um resultado assim;

```
var array_cores = ["azul", "amarelo", "verde", "azul"];
```

Agora preciso contar as repetições

Comment: O `id` deve ser único em cada página.

Comment: Desculpe, errei na hora de escrever aqui, estão como classes, vou arrumar

Comment: Uma função que monte um array dos nomes das classes e a quantidades de repetições dessa classe

Comment: ahh entendi....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar um array de objetos com as quantidades das classes. Um array de objetos fica fácil depois de pegar os valores:

```js
var cores = []; // cria a array;
$("#cores div").each(function(){
   var existe = false; // flag
   for(var x=0; x<cores.length; x++){ // percorre a array pra ver se já existe
      if(Object.keys(cores[x])[0] == this.className){
         existe = true;
         break; // se existe, altero a flag e paro o for
      }
   }
   
   if(!existe){
       var obj = {} // cria o objeto
       obj[this.className] = 1; // cria a chave com valor 1
       cores.push(obj); // adiciona o objeto na array
   }else{
       cores[x][this.className] = cores[x][this.className]+1; // soma mais um na quatidade
   }
});
console.log(cores);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cores">
    <div class="azul">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>       
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>       
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>       
    <div class="branco">conteúdo </div>       
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara era isso mesmo que eu queria, obrigado, preciso aprender a trabalhar com objetos

Comment: Legal! Dei uma atualizada, acho que ficou melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o selector do jQuery pra fazer isso! Porém, os ids devem ser únicos. Então, use classes. Snippet abaixo:

```js
console.log($('div#cores div.azul').length, 'azuis')
console.log($('div#cores div.amarelo').length, 'amarelos')
console.log($('div#cores div.verde').length, 'verdes')
```

```css
.verde {
  color: green
}

.azul {
  color: blue
}

.amarelo {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cores">
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>       
</div>
```

O selector `$('div#cores div.azul').length` pega as divs com classe azul que estão dentro da div com o id cores.

**EDITADO**

O snippet abaixo faz exatamente o que você deseja:

```js
const listaClasses = {}

$('div').each((index,tag) => {
    var classes = $(tag).attr('class') // Busca as classes de cada div
    if(classes != undefined){
      classes.split(' ').map((classe) => { // Separa cada tag e insere no arranjo
         if(classe != undefined){
           listaClasses[classe] = 0 // Define o contador como 0
         }
      })
   }  
})

console.log(listaClasses) // Exibe quais classes existem

const classes = Object.keys(listaClasses)

classes.map(classe => {
  listaClasses[classe] = $(`.${classe}`).length // Grava a quantidade de cada classe
}) // Verifica quais contém cada classe

console.log(listaClasses)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cores">
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="amarelo">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>
    <div class="azul">conteúdo </div>
    <div class="verde">conteúdo</div>       
</div>
```

## Referências

- [jQuery.selector()](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [Arrow function ( ) => { }](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Então, mas, daí eu precisaria saber os nomes das classes que estarão na páginas, tem como fazer uma função que ele varra a página e informe que nesta páginas existem 10 divs com a classe "x", 5 divs com a classe "Y", sem eu presquisar pelo nome da classe?

Comment: Bom, isso é muito específico! O selector precisa de algo definido para fazer a busca. Você poderia ter um arranjo com todas as classes, e um `for` que iria procurar cada classe dentro da página

Comment: Se quiser, posso adicionar um exemplo à minha resposta, caso tenha ficado confuso

Comment: @AlêMoraes , feito. Dá uma olhada no snippet que acrescentei!

Comment: Valeu cara, eu consegui com each fazer uma array só com os nomes das classes, agora vou fazer de novo um each nessa array, vou incluir na pergunta

Comment: Se minha resposta solucionou seu problema, por favor, marque-a como solução! Obrigado!